# How to find correlation between two values and remove noise?

Tags: signal-processing, python

I have two curves `A` and `B` like that are highly correlated as shown in the figure below where `C` is the pearson correlation between `A` and `B`.

The file containing the data can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dakxpehajzqirie/prova.csv?dl=0)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt

df = pd.read_csv('prova.csv')
A = df['A'].values
B = df['B'].values
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr 
C = pearsonr(A,B)[0]


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(20, 5))
ax1 = ax[0]
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(A, 'g-')
ax2.plot(B, 'b-')
ax1.set_ylabel('A', color='g', fontsize=20);
ax2.set_ylabel('B', color='b', fontsize=20);


ax2 = ax[1]
txt = 'C = %.2f'%C
ax2.scatter(A, B, label=txt)
ax2.set_xlabel('A', color='g', fontsize=20);
ax2.set_ylabel('B', color='b', fontsize=20);
ax2.legend(fontsize = 16)
```

The values of the green curve should be `0` but the signal is affected by `B`. I would like to know how to remove the values to find the relation between `A` and `B` in order to be `A` equale to zero.

[image]